# System.Reflection.TargetException error

Tags: c#, properties, system.reflection, getproperty

I have a main class where I am looping through each internal property in my cleats class property. Each internal property in my cleats class is of type `BeltProperty` (another class that contains information like value and id's).

```
private ObservableCollection<Cleats> _Cleats = new ObservableCollection<Cleats>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Cleats
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Cleats> Cleats { get { return _Cleats; } }

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Cleats)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    BeltProperty bp = new BeltProperty();
    bp = (BeltProperty)Cleats[Configurator_2016.Cleats.SelectedConfigurationIndex]
        .GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .GetValue(this, null);
    //rest of the code...
}
```

On the first `BeltProperty` it finds it throws a `System.Reflection.TargetException`. I want to know if there is another/better way to get the property from my cleats class. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Probably it's because of your send `this` as the target parameter to the `GetValue` method. but your code is not clear. What is `Cleats.GetProperties` ? what is `Cleats[Configurator_2016.Cleats.SelectedConfigurationIndex]`? be sure to post all relevant code

Comment: I tried using Cleats instead of this in getValue and still has the same result.

Comment: @andrewvb what's the type of `Cleats`? Method `GetProperties` is strange, at least it's not clear where it is located.

Comment: Cleats is of type Cleats class. Sorry I know its a bit confusing to explain. GetProperties is a method in the public abstract class type : MemberInfo, _Type, IReflect. Also Cleats.GetProperties should be typeof(Cleats).GetProperties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first i would choose better names for the classes and instances.
`ObservableCollection<Cleats> Cleats` is not straight forward.

The issue you are having is because of `this` parameter in `.GetValue(this, null);`

This parameter should be the instance that you are trying to read the property from.

The whole code could look like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Cleats)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    var bp = (BeltProperty)prop.GetValue(Cleats[Configurator_2016.Cleats.SelectedConfigurationIndex])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right, I had the GetValue contents wrong and I had to specify the correct object.